# NodeJS process.pid is the same across server instances

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, server, pid

For some server code I was working on I was creating message queues and needed unique names. The names were build using a number of environment items with the final item being the `process.pid`.  All of our server code is wrapped up in a Docker container and that container is run on the various server instances in the various regions.  When looking at the log statements we noticed that pid values were the same on both instances of our server on each region it was deployed.
I realize the Docker images are clones of one another and my DevOps guy says that then they should be the same, but give our pid numbers were in like the 65xx range, I find it hard to believe that our app process instances ended up with the same numbers.
The The other odd thing here, is that the pid values were only shared across a given AWS region.  So our us-east instances shared one pid, our us-west instances shared another.  The two numbers were close, maybe something like 6529 and 6631.
I think my question is how is the pid generated, because the manner in which I think it would be created must be in error.

Answer (score 0):

Each container runs in its own process space.  The main process of the container (its ENTRYPOINT if one was declared, or its CMD if not) always has process ID 1 (with the rights and responsibilities that entails).

In the very typical case where you have a Node container whose Dockerfile ends with something like `CMD ["npm", "start"]` I'd expect the reported pid to always be a very small number like 1 or 2.  If you introduce layers like a dedicated init process or a multi-process supervisor or a complex entrypoint setup I could see it being higher; but you should often expect that the process ID space will start with 1, and the container startup will do a consistent set of things using up a consistent number of pids, and you shouldn't be surprised to see the server process have a very consistent process ID.

(Try `docker exec ... ps -e` on any container you have running; you will probably see single-digit process IDs on *every* container.)